# Mysql query across tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a table `wp_views`, with columns `postid` and `views`
I want to get the IDs that have the highest values of `views` (top 4)
Then return the `title` and `link` from `wp_posts` using the `postid`.

What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: can you provide table structures? you need to use LEFT JOIN it seems join tables when you select.

Comment: Is that a typo and you meant `views` and not `value`?

Comment: @IgorYavych yes it was.

Comment: @Farside under 'wp_views' are 'postid' and 'views'. under 'wp_posts' are ID, post_title, guid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```
global $wpdb;
$top4=$wpdb->get_results('SELECT post_title, post_name from `'.$wpdb->prefix.'views`       
INNER JOIN `'.$wpdb->prefix.'posts` ON `postid`=`ID` 
ORDER BY `views` DESC 
LIMIT 4;', ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work, can  you also help me in substituting this to my to my $my_query? http://pastebin.com/D3SYEmmf

Comment: You can't use this with `wp_query`. And you can't query custom tables with `wp_query`. There are two solutions: a. if you want to keep using `wp_query`, you'll have to move your views data to`wp_postmeta` table (there is no need for a table just for these 2 columns anyway) and then just add meta query to your current `wp_query`. b. Alter this query with joins to `wp_tems`, `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy` for category and some other (`wp_postmeta`?) for sticky status.

Comment: Yes Im planning to remove the wp_query and display the result maybe using foreach, but I'm not very literate in this

Comment: something like <?php
  echo "<ul>";
 foreach($array){
     echo "<li><a href=".$link.">".$post_title."</a>""</li>";   

 }
 echo "</ul>";
?>
I'm not really sure, but I think it will look like this

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replicate your table structure from what your write and from this i have come up with the following:

```
SELECT id, title, link
FROM wp_views RIGHT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.id = wp_views.post_id
ORDER BY views DESC
LIMIT 4;
```

you can try it out here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cea23/1

I am using `RIGHT JOIN` to allow null values in the wp_posts part of the result. If you want to avoid NULL values in your results you can use `INNER JOIN` instead.